# Web Page show Ngnix page and doesn't show my index

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

Is the first time that I do a deploy in digital ocean, so I'm new at this.I'm using nginx and gunicorn.This is my configuration in nginx.

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mypage.com;
    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /root/.virtualenvs/rad/static/;
    }

     location / {
            proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header    Host $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I doesn't show my index page, only shows nginx page, I know is working 'cause if I put a url manualy it opens.

Comment: where are you working on nginx??? Local machine or hosting it somewhere else?

Comment: what WSGI are you using? Gunicorn?

Comment: Working in hosting, digital ocean, with gunicorn and nginx

Comment: This worked for me today: http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/08/minimal-nginx-and-gunicorn-configuration-for-djang/

Comment: You have a syntax error - missing space between `X-Forwarded-For` and `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for`